# Order a Collection by a List<int>

Tags: .net, linq, enumerable

I have a `Collection` of `Products`. Each product has a ProductId (int) property.  I also have a `List<int>` with one entry for each ProductId.  I need to order by `Collection<Products>` by the `List<int>`.  Is this possible using **LINQ** or some other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var res = orig.OrderBy(p => orderSettingList.IndexOf(p.ProductId));
```

Note that the products the value of the property for which are not in the list will sort ahead of all other products.

Answer (score 0):

I think a join would be the most efficient way of doing this, given it uses a dictionary internally.

```
orderSettingList.Join(orig, l => l, p => p.ProductId, (l, p) => p);
```